# PHP dual sort with array or use two mysql queries?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query as below:

`SELECT name, sort, categoryname, Count(distinct categoryname) AS count FROM articles ORDER BY categoryname, sort`

I need to display by grouping the categories and then **list the articles** by sort.

So it should look like

```
catName1
  article1
  article2
catName2
  article3
  article4
etc
```

Is it faster to create an array in php and loop through the categories and only query once or have two queries and loop.

Comment: Yes, one query will be faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, MySQL will be faster to execute data manipulation, and one query is generally more efficient than two.

However, PHP is much easier to scale out than MySQL for large numbers of requests. This means there will be a point at which it will be faster (though still less efficient) to use PHP for data manipulation.